# run ASP.NET Core app under Linux on startup

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, nginx, asp.net-core

I would like to run my ASP.NET Core solution under linux with the result it runs on startup.

From Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx), there are 2 ways: **Apache** and **Nginx**.

Both approaches involve **proxy pass**, e.g.

Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ....
```

Nginx:

```
server {
    listen        80;
    server_name   example.com *.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
        ...
```

Since Apache or Nginx only acts as proxy - do I get it right that **I have to manually start the dotnet app**?

I can't see the bit in the documentation where something could trigger `dotnet run` command against my WebApi project.

Obviously, Apache or Nginx wouldn't handle triggering dotnet app - unless I've missed something.

**Is there a way to automatically start the app on OS startup**?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[This section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#create-the-service-file) in docs describes, how to create a service file to automatically start your Asp.Net Core app.

> Create the service definition file:
>
> ```
> sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/kestrel-hellomvc.service
> ```
>
> The following is an example service file for the app:
>
> ```
> [Unit]
> Description=Example .NET Web API App running on Ubuntu
>
> [Service]
> WorkingDirectory=/var/aspnetcore/hellomvc
> ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/aspnetcore/hellomvc/hellomvc.dll
> Restart=always
> # Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
> RestartSec=10
> SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
> User=www-data
> Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
>
> [Install]
> WantedBy=multi-user.target
> ```
>
> Save the file and enable the service.
>
> ```
> systemctl enable kestrel-hellomvc.service
> ```
>
> Start the service and verify that it's running.
>
> ```
> systemctl start kestrel-hellomvc.service
> systemctl status kestrel-hellomvc.service
> ```

You need to set `WorkingDirectory` - path to folder with your app and `ExecStart` - with path to your app dll. By default this is enough.

From now, your app will **automatically start on OS startup** and will try to **restart after crashes**.

Comment: For anyone else who run into the problem I did; The User must be set to root if you want your application to bind on a port <= 1024

Comment: If you don't enable the service, it will work until the next "reboot" of the system.