# Why I can't set my dotnet program run at startup in Linux?

Tags: .net, linux, .net-core, raspberry-pi

My program is running on raspberry with raspberry OS.
My dotnet runtime is located on /home/pi/.dotnet
My program is located on /home/pi/deployment-location
I usually run my dotnet5 ConsoleApp like this:

```
cd deployment-location
dotnet ConsoleApp1.dll
```

And it runs successfully.
Now I want the program run at startup and I followed this tutorial to achieve it:[run ASP.NET Core app under Linux on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51354868/run-asp-net-core-app-under-linux-on-startup)

And here is my code:

```
[Unit]
Description=Example .NET App

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/deployment-location
ExecStart=/home/pi/.dotnet/dotnet /home/pi/deployment-location/ConsoleApp1.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
User=pi
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then it runs

```
systemctl enable ConsoleApp1.service
```

Successfully

However, after I run the

```
systemctl start ConsoleApp1.service
```

It reports can not run the service, then I run the

```
systemctl status ConsoleApp1.service
```

It reports these below:

```
● ConsoleApp1.service - Example .NET App running on Ubuntu
   Loaded: bad-setting (Reason: Unit ConsoleApp1.service has a bad unit file setting.)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Nov 05 02:03:27 raspberrypi systemd[1]:/etc/systemd/system/ConsoleApp1.service:5: Executable "dotnet" not found in path  “/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:"
```

What's wrong with my code? Thank you.

Comment: Could you please include the full/exact output from `systemctl start ...` and `systemctl status ...`? Is there anything relevant in the journal (`journactl -xe`)?

Comment: @omajid ● ConsoleApp1.service - Example .NET Web API App running on Ubuntu
   Loaded: bad-setting (Reason: Unit ConsoleApp1.service has a bad unit file setting.)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Nov 05 02:03:27 raspberrypi systemd[1]:/etc/systemd/system/ConsoleApp1.service:5: Executable "dotnet" not found in path  “/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:"

Comment: Sounds like you made changes to your unit file but systemd doesn't see it. Can you try a `systemctl daemon-reload` and then `systemctl start ...` again?

Comment: @omajid Yes, now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment "Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development", in my case it worked.

This line i think set app.Environment.IsDevelopment() = true

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).